# Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ satisfy $\sum_1^n |f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1})|^2 < 100$ for any $ \leq t_0 < t_1 < ...< t_n \leq 1$. Prove $f$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, problem-solving, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

> Suppose $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be such that $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n |f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1})|^2 < 100$$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$ and $0 \leq t_0 < \cdots < t_n \leq 1$. Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. If we can find a partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ such that $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$, then we would be done. by using the fact that $b-a \leq (b-a)^2 + \frac{1}{4}$ for any real numbers $a,b$, I have proven the inequality when $\epsilon \geq 1/4$. However, I am stuck on how to prove the case for $\epsilon < 1/4$. I would greatly appreciate any help. What is the intuition on the given condition, as well as how to think of this problem?

Comment: Note the condition implies there is only a finite number of points $x$ where $\lim_{r\downarrow 0}(\sup_{[x-r,x+r]} f-\inf_{[x-r,x+r]} f)>\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @user10354138 thanks for your comment. Could you tell me why that is so, and how that may help in solving the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be a partition of $[0,1]$. By AM-QM,
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(t_{i}) - f(t_{i-1})| \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(t_{i}) - f(t_{i-1})|^{2}} <\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(t_{i}) - f(t_{i-1})| < 10\sqrt{n}$$
Let $P$ be the partition that partitions $[0,1]$ into intervals of length $1/n$. Choose $c_{i}$ and $c_{i}'$ such that $\sup_{x \in [t_{i-1},t_{i}]}f(x)  - \frac{1}{n} < f(c_{i})$ and $\inf_{x\in [t_{i-1},t_{i}]}f(x) + \frac{1}{n} > f(c_{i}')$. We note the set of all $c_{i}$ and $c_{i}'$ form a partition of $[0,1]$. Then,
\begin{align}
U(f,P) - L(f,P) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sup_{x\in [t_{i-1},t_{i}]} f(x)(t_{i}-t_{i-1}) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf_{x\in [t_{i-1},t_{i}]} f(x)(t_{i}-t_{i-1}) \\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sup_{x\in [t_{i-1},t_{i}]}f(x)-\inf_{x\in [t_{i-1},t_{i}]}f(x)\right) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(|f(c_{i}) - f(c_{i}')| + \frac{2}{n}\right) \\
&<\frac{1}{n}\left(20\sqrt{n} + 2\right) \\
&\leq \frac{22}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align}
We can choose $n$ appropriately given an $\varepsilon$ and it then follows that $f$ is Riemann integrable.